# How to load an image from a URL into a PHP script and encode it as a base64 string?

Tags: php, image, file-get-contents

I want to fetch an image from a URL, basically a resizing service, and then convert it to base64 string for consumption at client side.

I use the following code,

```php
$imagePath = "www.xyz.com/resize/view.php?image=../pictures/abc.jpg&mode=crop&size=200x200";
$image = imagecreatefromstring(file_get_contents($imagePath));
$thumb_encoded = base64_encode($image);
echo "<br>".$thumb_encoded;
```

The $imagePath value, when opened in a browser works fine. Image is displayed.
But when running this script, the PHP throws the following error,

> PHP Warning:  file_get_contents(www.xyz.com/resize/view.php?image=../../pictures/abc.jpg&\amp;mode=crop&\amp;size=200x200): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in resizeImage.php on line 12

The & params in the URL which are needed for $_GET are getting converted to &\amp; while making the request in the PHP script.
I have tried urlencode() and htmlspecialchars($url) and html_entity_decode() and also escape characters, but in vain. I get the same/similar issues.
The image wont just load, the URL which the script queries is Wrong.
Can someone point out the issue here and help me?

Comment: don't dump images directly into the database, it will be SLOW!!!!  Instead run an image upload script, and store the paths.

Comment: I am not dumping into Database. Just encoding it as base64 and emitting it out for JSON. The URL gets modified such that the & changes to &amp;  , and thats my only problem as of now.

Comment: That's JSON then, not PHP.

Comment: Post the code from resizeImage.php on line 12

Comment: I tried your parameters on a vm by appending `?image=../pictures/abc.jpg&mode=crop&size=200x200` to the url and a `var_dump($_GET)` gave me:-`array (size=3)
  'image' => string '../pictures/abc.jpg' (length=19)
  'mode' => string 'crop' (length=4)
  'size' => string '200x200' (length=7)` Which looks about right to me.

Comment: The `&\amp;` is just part of the error message, I doubt they exist in the string being sent. Check with a var_dump(). They are not the problem. The problem the error message is telling you about is that `www.xyz.com/resize/view.php?image=../pictures/abc.jpg&mode=crop&size=200x200` is a url that does not exist.

Comment: Also. ensure [allow_url_fopen](http://php.net/manual/en/filesystem.configuration.php#ini.allow-url-fopen) is set in php.ini

Comment: @machineaddict : code line is,         $image = imagecreatefromstring(file_get_contents($imagePath));

Comment: @vascowhite when i do an echo $imagePath, i get the correct value. While, in the php error log its  &amp; There is no \ .

Comment: I'm assuming `$imagePath` in `resizeImage.php` is relative. Always use absolute paths and you will never get in trouble. Use `var_dump($imagePath)` in `resizeImage.php` on line 11 and see what is the output.

Comment: I tried that @machineaddict .

Comment: I tried that @machineaddict The var_dump outputs the exact URL which is viewable in a browser. And i cannot use the absolute path, the permissions are such that, if i use the absolute path the image is inaccessible, while with this relative path it works fine (in the browser). It feels like that the file_get_contents function is modifying this url somehow. Though i doubt if it can be the case, can it be?

Comment: The permissions either allow to use relative and absolute paths, either not. Please include in your question the whole code from `resizeImage.php` so I can test it out.

Comment: here is the code @machineaddict. With this code i get the 404 Not Found error, now that the http:// is appended to the URL. `<?php
include_once("../../library/config.php");
if( file_exists( DOCUMENT_ROOT.'pictures/destination/1733.jpg') ) {
        $imgPath ='http://www.trodly.com/library/resize/view.php?image=../../pictures/destination/1733.jpg&mode=crop&size=200x200';
        $image = file_get_contents($imgPath);
        $thumb_encoded = base64_encode($image);
        echo "<br>".$thumb_encoded;
}
?>
`

Comment: php log is:   [Sat Jun 06 10:05:47 2015] [error] [client 117.216.192.149] PHP Warning:  file_get_contents(http://www.trodly.com/library/resize/view.php?image=../../pictures/destination/1733.jpg&amp;mode=crop&amp;size=200x200): failed to open stream: HTTP request failed! HTTP/1.1 404 Not Found\r